# How to draw a line using getX() and getY()?

Tags: java

This is for a much larger homework assignment.
How do I draw a line using getX() and getY()?
Here is my code, please help.

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Line extends Rectangle {
    /**
    * Constructor.  Just passes the params to the Rectangle constructor.
    */
    public Line(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color lineColor, Color fillColor, boolean fill) {
        super(x, y, w, h, lineColor, fillColor, fill);
    }

    /*
    * Override Rectangle draw(Graphics g) method.
    */
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // Be nice. Save the state of the object before changing it.
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();

        g.setColor(getLineColor());
        g.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        // Set the state back when done.
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }

    /**
    * Returns a String that represents this object.
    */
    public String toString() {
        //return "Line: \n\tx = " + getX() + "\n\ty = " + getY() + "\n\tw = " + getWidth() + "\n\th = " + getHeight();
        return "Line";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Line extends Rectangle` does not make much sense.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the behavior of the code you pasted.  Was there something in particular you expected to happen that did not?

Comment: If you are trying to draw a diagonal for the rectangle,try  `g.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getX()+getWidth(), getY()+getHeight())`

Comment: I love it when someone answers a direct question with a direct answer. That is exactly what worked Nishan...thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the arguments in your `drawline(...)` method.

```
drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
```

draws a line from point(x1, y1) to point(x2, y2).  There is no such thing as drawing a line from one point with a height and width.